# Incomplete configuration of ubuntu system at the first time, how to restart?

Tags: system-installation, configuration

I just bought a Dell laptop with Ubuntu16.04.
At the first time I switched on the computer, it goes into the setting interface, like setting language, setting username. Since I didn't have a network at that time, it was incomplete.

Now I try to continue the configuration, but I don't know how to restart the install/setting window? 
Now I can only see a guest account in the login interface.

Is there a way to solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: You mentioned setting username. So you did create a user during the configuration, right ?

Comment: At the worst, since it's a new computer and you're starting from scratch, make a Live USB and reinstall from that... it takes less than 1/2 hour. https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0

Comment: well, I solved the issue by reinstall the system. Thanks for your comments.